# Errors compiling MVVMCross project after updating to xamarin.android 4.10.1

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have updated to Xamarin.Android 4.10.1 and now my MvvmCross project does not compile :( its as if it cant find any of the MVX attributes.

I am getting an error like the following for every MvvmCross entry in my code
E:\Software Projects\xxx\xxx\xxx\Resources\layout\xxx.xml(0,0): Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'MvxBind' in package 'com.xxx' (xxx)

has anyone encountered this too?

Thanks

Amit

Comment: It gets even weirder. I downloaded the mvvmcross tutorials and loaded a project and it compiles. No I am really at a loss... Maybe I should just start a new solution and start copying everything file by file...

Comment: I have narrowed it down. Once I add the GooglePlayServicesLib.dll I get the error stated above. How can this be? I have tried updating to ver12 but its no help